# How to grab and rotate an object on fixed position on unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am trying to make a game in Unity that when the player (with oculus quest controller) grab the object he can rotate it without moving the object ,on a fixed position. I am having problem with transforming the local position of the controllers to the locale position of the object and rotate it with c#. please help me I am still new in this.

**edit: here is the last I tried:

```
[Header("Controller")]
public OVRInput.Button grabButton;

public GameObject target;
public float speed=0.01f;
//Quaternion m_MyQuaternion;
public Vector3 targetPosition;

  void Update()
{

    if (OVRInput.Get(grabButton))
    {
        targetPosition = new Vector3(taregt_eulerAngX, taregt_eulerAngY, target_eulerAngZ);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, targetPosition) > 0.01f)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, targetPosition, Time.time * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

the target in this case is the left hand, so when I grab the gameobj it will rotate accordingly to the hand(controller)

Comment: What have you tried, do you have some example code so far?

Comment: I added the example to the question, it is rotating but not right.